# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined component issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, routes, config

I'm getting an error called **Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined** in my newly built react-app after register and login which I'm unable to find the solution.

Here's => the **[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-minsky-jmwhi?file=/src/App/App.jsx)**

and the screen [image]

Seems like the error is for the private route

Please find the code piece below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        localStorage.getItem('user')
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )} />
)
```

Need Solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like export issue
Please export he QuizPage like this

```js
const connectedQuizPage = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
export { connectedQuizPage as QuizPage };
```